# Remove Radio Buttons from a Quiz

Tags: javascript, html

We are trying to get a Quiz written in Javascript running on our site. We need to remove Radio buttons because currently, they are not linking through to the next question.

Here is the page in question:

http://stephanieshipper.com/test/

And below is the piece of code from the .js file that contains the Radio buttons. How would I remove these without breaking the rest of the functionality? So far, when I have taken out the Radio buttons, the text links also break.

```js
function updates(questions) {

 for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

  $("body").append("<article><p>" + questions[i] + "</p><input id='question-" + (i*10) + "-1' type='radio' order='1' name='question-" + i + "-0'><label for='question-" + (i*10) + "-1'>exactly like me</label><br><input id='question-" + (i*100) + "-2' type='radio' order='2' name='question-" + i + "-0'><label for='question-" + (i*100) + "-2'>sort of like me</label><br><input id='question-" + (i*1000) + "-3' type='radio' order='3' name='question-" + i + "-0'><label for='question-" + (i*1000) + "-3'>not really like me</label><br><input id='question-" + (i*10000) + "-4' type='radio' order='4' name='question-" + i + "-0'><label for='question-" + (i*1000) + "-4'>not at all like me</label><br></article>");

 }

 motions();

}



function motions() {

 var step = 1;

 results = [];

 var order;

 $("body > article > label").on("click", function() {

  $(this).parent().hide(250);

  if (step < 20) {

   $(this).parent().next().show(250);

   order = parseInt($(this).prev().attr("order"));

   results[step-1] = order;

   step++;

  } else {
```

Comment: Partial code...what's after `else`?

Comment: Remove `type='radio'` but you'll get text boxes by default. Change `type='radio'` to `type='button'`...or replace each `<input>` with either an `<a>`nchor or a `<button>`